# How does calling this function object work?

Tags: c++, functor

I have a class

```
class fobj{
public:
    fobj(int i):id(i) {}

    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout<<"Prints"<<std::endl;
    }

private:
    int id;
};

template<typename T>
void func(T type)
{
   type();
}
```

If I invoke `func` like

Method 1:

```
func(fobj(1));
```

the message I wanted to print is printed.

I was always thinking I needed to do something like

Method 2:

```
fobj Iobj(1); // create an instance of the fobj class
func(Iobj);   // call func by passing Iobj(which is a function object)
```

How does Method 1 work? I mean what exactly happens?

And how is a call made to the operator() in class fobj ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that this works because your template class is taking an object by value:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T type)   // this takes a T by value
...
```

because of this, it can take either an lvalue (such as an actual variable) or an rvalue (such as the temporary).

If for some reason you did want to limit `func` to only taking an lvalue, you could modify the function to using pass by reference:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T &type)  // this takes a T by reference
...
```

using pass by reference does allow the side effect of the function being able to modify the object.

Comment: One advantage of posting in Stack Overflow is the amazing replies :). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `func(fobj(1))`, `fobj(1)` creates a temporay `fobj` from the literal `int` 1. This temporary is used to initialized the function parameter `type` (there's an implicit copy which the compiler may elide), and in the body of the function `operator()` is invoked on the function object.

I think that naming the function parameter `type` is a bit misleading. `type` is the name of the `T` instance (in this case a `fobj`) that is the function parameter.